# retrieving user name and password from database

Tags: authentication, passwords, blackberry-10

I'm making an app which requires to enter user name and password on the log in page. 
How to retrieve user name and password from database in blackberry 10 cascades ? please mention the code ....

Comment: Where do you want this database? You should never save the actual password, and you only check if it is correct, not retreive it.

Comment: i'm sorry.... the database i'm using is sqlite. I actually wanted to make authentication such that, if the credentials entered by the user are correct,only then he will be redirected to the main qml page.

Comment: please provide correct code possible for it

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i need to get the list username and password from the database and compare with my username and password  in the textbox

Comment: does using iterator solve the problem???????/

Comment: No, that's silly. You can check with SQL (WHERE), or just get the matching user and check if password hashes hatch. I would suggest you read a bit about security

Comment: i'm least bother about security.It's a simple app which doesn't require very high and complicated security.Please give me the code to set a textbox's text retrieve from database.

Comment: please Bojan Kogoj ! need your help ....

Answer (score 0):

Get a require user and password from database by result set.

```
String user=usertx.getText();
char[] password=pswdtx.getPassword();
String pswd=String.valueOf(password);   \\here is important to put a char password in string.`
```

We call the require user and his password by:

```
Resultset rs= stmt.excuteQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME='"+user+"' AND PASSWORD='"+pswd+"'");
```

This code will get only the row of selected user and his information on row and set it in (rs). Code of `rs.next()`:

```
while(rs.next()){
    rsuser=rs.getString("NAME");         //get user and set it in rsuser.
    rspswd=rs.getString("PASSWORD");}    //get password and set it in rspswd.
if ((user.equals(rsuser)) && (pswd.equals(rspswd))){  //the equevlant statment.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password exist");}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Check Username and Password ");}
}
```

here is whole of code:

```
private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try {
        String user=usertx.getText();
        char[] password=pswdtx.getPassword();
        String pswd=String.valueOf(password);

        String rsuser=null;
        String rspswd=null;
        String Q="SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME='"+user+"' AND PASSWORD='"+pswd+"'";
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(Q);

        while(rs.next()){
        rsuser=rs.getString("NAME");
        rspswd=rs.getString("PASSWORD");}
        if ((user.equals(rsuser)) && (pswd.equals(rspswd))){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password exist");}
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Check Username and Password ");}
        } 
    catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line to your .pro file
LIBS   += -lbbdata

Then you can write the following code:

```
    QVariant searchResult;
    QVariantList searchList;
    QString userName, password;

    bb::data::SqlDataAccess sda(QDir::currentPath() + "/app/native/assets/sample.sqlite");

    searchResult = sda.execute("select * from usersTable where userId=5");
    searchList = searchResult.value<QVariantList>();

    userName = searchList.at(0).toMap()["name"];
    password = searchList.at(0).toMap()["password"];
```

Comment: S.Hamed ,  consider a database for example where a table has 5  columns with some corresponding records in it. On the other hand, consider a qml page which has 5 text-boxes/labels. Is it possible to map those text-boxes/labels with those of 5 columns of that database so that when a sql query is asked to retrieve data from multiple columns at-a-time(Example: select *from tablename where column1="****" and column2="***" .... ..... and column5="****")where resultant data from column1 is sent to the first text-box, the column2 sends the data to second text-box ... upto the 5th text-box ?

Comment: if it is possible, please provide the code.... hope u have understood my question ... thanks in advance